# SQL Count where clause

Tags: sql, join, count, where-clause, having

I have the the following SQL statement:

```
 SELECT        [l.LeagueId] AS LeagueId, [l.LeagueName] AS NAME, [lp.PositionId]
 FROM            (Leagues l INNER JOIN
                     Lineups lp ON l.LeagueId = lp.LeagueId)
 WHERE        (lp.PositionId = 1) OR
                     (lp.PositionId = 3) OR
                     (lp.PositionId = 2)
```

What I really need is to get the rows where the count of the position is greater than a number.  Something like:

```
 SELECT        [l.LeagueId] AS LeagueId, [l.LeagueName] AS NAME, [lp.PositionId]
 FROM            (Leagues l INNER JOIN
                     Lineups lp ON l.LeagueId = lp.LeagueId)
 WHERE        Count(lp.PositionId = 1) > 2 OR
                     Count(lp.PositionId = 3) > 6 OR
                     Count(lp.PositionId = 2) > 3
```

Is there any way to do this in SQL?

Comment: So, I'm using Cade Roux's solution below, but does anyone know why, when I change the HAVING from an OR statement to and AND statement, I get zero results?  If I only use one SUM(CASE..) statement, I get results, but if I combine two statement that worked, I get zero results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this?:

```
SELECT        [l.LeagueId] AS LeagueId, [l.LeagueName] AS NAME
 FROM            (Leagues l INNER JOIN
                     Lineups lp ON l.LeagueId = lp.LeagueId)
 GROUP BY [l.LeagueId], [l.LeagueName]
 HAVING        SUM(CASE WHEN lp.PositionId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 2 OR
                     SUM(CASE WHEN lp.PositionId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 6 OR
                     SUM(CASE WHEN lp.PositionId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 3
```

Answer (score 7):

HAVING is the keyword you're looking for:

```
SELECT        [l.LeagueId] AS LeagueId, [l.LeagueName] AS NAME, [lp.PositionId]
FROM            (Leagues l INNER JOIN
                     Lineups lp ON l.LeagueId = lp.LeagueId)
GROUP BY lp.PositionId, l.LeagueName
HAVING lp.PositionId = 1 AND COUNT(*) > 2 
       OR lp.PositionId = 2 AND COUNT(*) > 3 
       OR lp.PositionId = 3 AND COUNT(*) > 6
```