# Return Only Results with more than one Correct Choice

Tags: sql, sql-server, having

I need to come up with a query that will show which questions have more than one correct answer.  Been searching and could not find exactly what I need.  I found this, which is kinda what I want, but it didn't work for me, maybe i did it wrong.

[SQL Count where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440857/sql-count-where-clause)

Here is what I have so far...

```
SELECT pq.ItemID, pq.RevNum, pc.sequence, pc.correct FROM Choice pc 
JOIN Question pq on pc.UniqueQID = pq.UniqueQID and pc.RevNum = pq.RevNum
Group BY pq.ItemID, pq.RevNum, pc.Sequence, pc.Correct
ORDER BY ItemID, RevNum, Sequence
```

This returns a list of each question/revision and all there choices.  Results look like this...

```
ItemID      RevNum  Seq     Correct
12776   1   A   0
12776   1   B   0
12776   1   C   1

12777   1   A   0
12777   1   B   1
12777   1   C   0
12777   1   D   0

12778   1   A   1
12778   1   B   1
12778   1   C   0
12778   1   D   1

8301    3   a   1
8301    3   b   2
8301    3   c   2
8301    3   d   2

8303    3   a   2
8303    3   b   1
8303    3   c   2
8303    3   d   2
```

I added the new lines for clarity.  Choice = 1 correct, 0 or 2 is incorrect.  I need only questions which have more than one correct answer, such as 12778 above.

Based on the above linked article I tried something like this but it didn't work says error near = on Line 4.

```
SELECT pq.ItemID, pq.RevNum, pc.sequence, pc.correct FROM pubChoice pc 
JOIN pubQuestion pq on pc.UniqueQID = pq.UniqueQID and pc.RevNum = pq.RevNum
Group BY pq.ItemID, pq.RevNum, pc.Sequence, pc.Correct
HAVING Count(correct=1) > 1
ORDER BY ItemID, RevNum, Sequence
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need the records where correct is 1, so add it to a where clause. After this group on the others, and add a count(*), thus you can have a having clause on that count(*).
Something like this should work:

```
SELECT pq.ItemID, pq.RevNum, pc.sequence,count(*) FROM pubChoice pc 
JOIN pubQuestion pq on pc.UniqueQID = pq.UniqueQID and pc.RevNum = pq.RevNum
WHERE pc.Correct = 1
Group BY pq.ItemID, pq.RevNum, pc.Sequence
HAVING Count(*) > 1
ORDER BY ItemID, RevNum, Sequence
```

Comment: I do not want only records where correct is 1, it should not be in the where clause.

Comment: I only want records which have more than one choice that is correct.  What you said above definitely does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

How do you determine a choice is the correct one?  You'd need something like this:

```
SELECT pq.*
FROM Question pq
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT ItemID, COUNT(*) as correctCount
FROM Question q
INNER JOIN Choice c
ON c.UniqueQID = q.UniqueQID 
WHERE ANSWER_IS_CORRECT
GROUP BY ItemID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) mults
ON pq.ItemID = mults.ItemID
```

Note that I haven't tested this but it should theoretically work as long as you have a way to tell whether a choice is the correct one.  It will return all ItemIDs that have more than one correct answer, then join back to the questions on the ItemID to get all options on it (you may need to join back to choice).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and the initial question, it seems like this will work for you:

```
SELECT pq.ItemID, 
  pq.RevNum, 
  pc.sequence, 
  pc.correct 
FROM Choice pc 
JOIN Question pq 
  on pc.UniqueQID = pq.UniqueQID 
  and pc.RevNum = pq.RevNum
where exists (select count(*) TotalCorrect, UniqueQID, RevNum
              from choice c
              where correct = 1
                and pc.UniqueQID = c.UniqueQID
                and pc.RevNum = c.RevNum
              group by UniqueQID, RevNum
              having count(*) > 1);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06400/10)

The result is:

```
| ITEMID | REVNUM | SEQUENCE | CORRECT |
----------------------------------------
|  12778 |      1 |        A |       1 |
|  12778 |      1 |        B |       1 |
|  12778 |      1 |        C |       0 |
|  12778 |      1 |        D |       1 |
```